# I have an error in OrbitControls of Three.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I was starting a tutorial of JavaScript and Three.js and started very good, but when I put a control line, the program stopped, I check the console and have two errors, one of them is in my code:

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.OrbitControls is not a constructor.

The other seems to be in the OrbitControls.js archive in the first line, but it is all correct to me.

i already tried syntax error finders but it also dont help

```
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
    var scene = new THREE.Scene( );
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth 
        window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    //atualizando a visualização do cubo no navegador em diferentes proporções
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', function( )
    {
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight;
        renderer.setSize( width, height );
        camera.aspect = width / height;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix(   );
    } );

    //controle da câmera    

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); 

    //criação da forma    

    var geometry= new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );

    //criação de material, cor ou textura

    var material= new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:0xffffff, wireframe: true });
    var cube= new THREE.Mesh ( geometry, material );
    scene.add ( cube );  

    //posição da câmera    

    camera.position.z = 3;    

    //rotação
    var update = function ()
    {
       cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
       cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    };
    //cena que vai ser desenhada
    var render = function()
    {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    };
    //renderização das animações de maneira mais rapida
    var GameLoop = function()
    {
        requestAnimationFrame( GameLoop );

        update( );
        render( );
    };

    GameLoop(  );
```

The expected was have an orbital view of the cube controlled by the mouse

Comment: Probably it has to be `<script src="js/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js">`

Comment: i have tried but still doesnt working

Comment: Can you check the network tab of your browser console and verify if you get a HTTP 404 error for `OrbitControls.js`? If so, you have probably placed the file in the wrong directory.

Comment: I checked and the OrbitControls file has a connection start of 4.04, this is an error ?

Comment: Navigate your browser to your webpage. Remove any HTML file reference from the end of the URL, and append the path to `OrbitControls.js`. For example: `http://yoururl/index.html`=>`http://yoururl/three/OrbitControls.js`. Your browser should render the file as plain text. If you see an error rather than the script text, then `OrbitControls.js` is not referenced at the correct path.

Comment: TheJim01, i have maked this and shows me the script text, so i think is not directory error